# extract audio using ffmpeg and save wav files

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg has a way to extract video images using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i "video.avi" -vf fps=30 "images/frame_%09d.png" -hide_banner
```

Is there a way in ffmpeg to extract or cut audios into smaller chunks the same way that is done on the above command but the difference is it will create an audio file not an image file.

I tried the following but it only creates a wav file.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.avi" -vf fps=30 "images/frame_%09d.wav" -hide_banner
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove -vf option, you don't need it as you don't need video
2. Video frames can be assumed as single units, but what you want in audio? Sungle samples. huh? So, you must specify interval

For example:

```
    # ffmpeg -i "video.avi" -f segment -segment_time 3 -c copy "images/frame_%03d.mp3" -hide_banner
```